# Get github action version inside the action

Tags: github-actions

Consider a github action that:

1. downloads a binary
2. untars and runs the binary

The binary version depends on the version of the action. When the action is used like

```
uses: action_x@v3
```

I am trying to get the `v3` inside the action, so that I can map it to the corresponding binary version.

Is there a way to do this without having to hard-code the binary version on the yaml (and remember to bump it on release)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [GitHub Contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts), it seems that `github.action_ref` should contain what you are looking for:

> For a step executing an action, this is the ref of the action being executed. For example, `v2`.

```
jobs:
  show_checkout_version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: echo '${{ github.action_ref }}'
```